# How to disable frame and enable close/min/max button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to disable frame but button which is in upper menu in each frame (X-close ...) I want still enable

I try this:

```
frame.setEnable(true);
```

this works good on linux. These button are still active but in windows no. Is there options how to active them ?

Comment: this isn't possible on Windows platform, btw don't to play with decorations

Comment: Your best approach will probably be to create custom close/min/max buttons on an undecorated frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there options how to active them ?

Not that I know of.

You might be able to use the [Disabled Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/disabled-panel/).

Answer (score 0):

you can add a panel to your frame and add all your components to that panel. Later when you want to disable the contents just disable the inner panel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "frame.setResizable(true);" - to enable min/max button 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);- to close

frame.setEnabled(false);  to disable the frame.